# Transaction manager for tests

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I have a simple transaction manager implementation and I am wondering how best to handle my end-to-end integration tests.

In my test I invoke an action in my test which starts a transaction and does some work. As part of my test I want to do some assertions about the database work its done but I don't want to commit the transaction - I want to roll it back.

One way I can think to achieve this would be to override the transaction manager and make the commit method do nothing and invoke rollback at the end of the test.

One thing that concerned me with this approach is the caching that involved, how do I make sure that every action results in a database call rather than using any cache?

I figure this must be something that has been answered before - no point in reinventing the wheel, so am I doing the right thing?

If it matters, I am using Hibernate and NOT using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Make your test class transactional and do a rollback in an after test method.
You can do that in an abstract super class. So you do not have to do that in every integration test class.

You have to decide if it is a good idea to disable the cache in testing env or to use the cache. Using the cache may have side effects but you are closer to the reality. On the other hand you may want to test the dao layer and not the cache.